# EclipseLink: Retrieving PU name programmatically

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Creating an EMF in EclipseLink is simple enough:

```
String myPU = "mypu";
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(myPU);
```

However, is there any way to retrieve the name of the PU after the factory has been created, apart from storing the string separately?

Comment: Answer is JPA impl specific. You should knew that if you actually searched or Googled the question. So, improve the question to tell the JPA impl/version used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the persistenceUnitName in a properties map when creating the factory:

```
String myPU = "mypu";
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put("custom-property.unit-name", myPU);
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(myPU, properties);
assertEquals(myPU, emf.getProperties().get("custom-property.unit-name"));
```

The name of the property to store the unit name isn't special.  The factory simply stores whatever properties you pass to it.  Just be sure that it is unique and doesn't collide with one of the EclipseLink properties.